# FileUnput PrimeFaces não atualiza o atributo;

Tags: java, java-ee, primefaces, file-upload

Possuo uma estrutura de repetição:

```
<ui:repeat var="item" />
```

Dentro dela eu imprimo alguns campos. Um deles é o `<p:fileUpload/>`

Até ai tudo bem. O problema está na hora de fazer a ação, quando clico no botão de salvar ele atribui todos os campos no *managebran* menos o campo do *file*.

Mas se eu retirar o *fileInput* de dentro do `<ui:repeat>` ele funciona.

Além de não funcionar, o atributo do meu *bean* fica nulo.

```
<h:form>
<ui:repeat var="item" value="#{bean.page.columns}">
<p:fileUpload mode="simple" value="#{bean.file}" />
</ui:repeat>
<p:commandButton ajax="false" action="#{bean.save}" value="#{msgs.save}" 
 update="growl" styleClass="btn button" />
</h:form>
```

Assim funciona, ele associa o valor no meu *bean*.

```
<h:form>
<p:fileUpload mode="simple" value="#{bean.file}" />
<p:commandButton ajax="false" action="#{bean.save}" value="#{msgs.save}" 
 update="growl" styleClass="btn button" />
</h:form>
```

Comment: Evite usar o ui:repeat, de uma olhada no p:dataList.

Comment: Obrigado, vou dar uma olhada e vejo se adianta.

Comment: Já caí em um problema parecido (em uma dataTable). Uma solução é deixar todos os arquivos em uma lista ou array (veja essa resposta do [BalusC](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13051503/664577)). Para mim não funcionou pois os arquivos eram opcionais e eu não conseguia fazer *binding* apenas através do índice. O que fiz na época foi adaptar essa solução do BalusC para escrever os resultados em um Mapa <ID, Arquivo> e adaptar o método chamado no `commandButton` para associar cada arquivo à seu respectivo bean (infelizmente não tenho esse código comigo, mas se funfar eu crio uma resposta).

Answer (score 2):

seu formulário está utilizando o enctype padrão que é `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, para lidar requisições POST envolvendo binários, que o caso de um upload de arquivos, é necessário utilizar um enctype específico: `multipart/form-data`

configure seu form dessa forma:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Para fazer upload de múltiplos arquivos, é possível utilizar o atributo `multiple="true"` em seu `p:fileUpload`